# Php json of object missing some properties

Tags: php, json, class

I have a php class, when i `json_encode` the file, i dont get Total, Subtotal in the json string, how can i make this possible,

```
class sale{

public $Customer;
public $DiscountRate;
public $TaxRate;
public $SaleItems;

public function Total()
{
// ....
}
public function Subtotal()
{
// ....
}
}
```

Comment: json enccoding encodes the __properties__ of the instance, not the __methods__.... are you really expecting json_encode to automagically convert the PHP code (with all its potential dependencies, database access, etc) to javascript code?

Comment: No, but i need the value of total and subtotal encoded, so how do i achieve this

Comment: As John has suggested in his answer, [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) and add the results of those two calls as additional properties

Comment: pls can you help with an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply the `JsonSerializable` interface to your class and implement the `jsonSerialize()` method. The return value of this method will be used as the input to the `json_encode()` function.

```
class Sale implements JsonSerializable {

    public $customer;

    public function total() {
        return 40;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'customer' => $this->customer,
            'total' => $this->total()
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: pls can you help with an example?